# Streamsets Using Direct Engine REST APIs. This Data Collector is not accessible

Tags: connector, streamsets

I am getting an error in accessing the Streamsets Connector.  How do I change back to "Using Websocket Tunnelling?"

I've been using Streamsets version 4.1 for a short time.  The sales tech switched a configuration to use the "Direct Engine REST APIs."  That solved a problem with security when I wanted to connect to our test environment but made it so I could not use Streamsets in a local Docker instance.  I want to switch it back and I cannot find where the configuration setting is changed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two locations that may need to be changed to switch from "Using Direct Engine REST APIs" to "Using WebSocket Tunneling."  The main location is in the user browser settings found by clicking on the user icon in the top right corner and the selecting the "Browser Settings" menu next to "Account Settings."  If the option is unavailable select the "My Organization" in the left hand menu and click on the "Advanced..." button.  Then select the "Enable WebSocket Tunneling for UI Communication" checkbox in the right column.  After enabling it for the organization, you can go back to the browser settings and update it there.